# Regarding multiple topics partition assignment to a consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Assume a kafka consumer group is subscribed to 2 topics. Both the topics have only one partition. Does Kafka assign both the topic's partition to the same consumer in the consumer group? or is it possible that kafka assigns topic 1's partition to consumer 1 and topic 2's partition to consumer 2,...

Comment: This sounds like a [XY PRoblem](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you describe more on **what** you are actually trying to achieve? If you just create a new ConsumerGroup any old ConsumerGroup will not be impacted.

Comment: Have edited the question mike.

Comment: how many instances has the Kafka consumer group which is subscribed to 2 topics? What do you mean with "consumer 1" and "consumer 2"?

Comment: number of instances is configurable. usually more than 1. I named instance/process 1 as consumer 1 and instance/process 2 as consumer 2 who are in the same consumer group.